# neo4j-shell.bat error Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory

Tags: neo4j

```
neo4j-shell.bat -path c:\_neo\bank\bank -file app.cypher
```

this used to work in `neo4j` 2.3.3, but it fails in 3.0.0 with the following error

```
Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, c:\_neo\bank\bank
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve this by adding neo4j_home environment variable.